# Recording MIDI from electronic drums

Tags: recording, midi, electronic

I am trying to record a MIDI track using my electronic drums D-Tronic Q2 Plus.
The only output the drum model has is USB output. So I tried to connect my drums with my PC via USB-USB cable. I also installed LoopBe1 Virtual MIDI device (http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html) and connect an instrument track in Cubase with this virtual port. But nothing is recording.

The question is - can I read MIDI data from my drums via USB-USB cable? And if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need a virtual MIDI port?`Just tell Cubase to record from the real port.

Comment: the "real" port is USB port. Can I tell cubase to use USB port?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: MY OS is Windows 7

Comment: Windows 7 has a built-in USB MIDI driver. How exactly does this device show up in Device Manager?

Comment: It does not show up at all. http://www.jpeg.cz/images/2014/06/13/5goq4.png

Comment: I meant the Windows Device Manager.

Comment: it looks like this : http://jpeg.cz/images/2014/06/13/V3QI6.png

Comment: Do you have any other USB audio device? What's the error of that USB controller?

Comment: I have several USB devices - mouse, M-Audio audio card, flash drive and the drums. The error is: The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

Comment: Is that "USB Audio Device" the drums?

Comment: yes it is, maybe the driver is missing, but I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: If it shows up as "USB Audio Device", the device driver works correctly. I don't know anything about Cubase.

Answer (score 0):

as CL said you don't need virtual Midi port.
all you need is going to midi devices settings in cubase and check if your drum has been recognized there or not. if not maybe you need to install a usb midi driver for your instrument if any available or create a midi instrument manually in cubase midi devices settings which is suitable for your needs. but usually your OS should recognize your instrument az well.
sorry its about 2 years I'm not using cubase any more so I'm not sure about the name if "midi devices settings".

Comment: I cant find any driver for my drums and the driver isnt automatically installed. How can I install my own MIDI device reading from USB port?